# A tool for unveiling the underlying disease

Tags: grammar

"A tool for unveiling the underlying disease"

Does this correct?

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: My friend said this sounds a bit odd, though he is not a native speaker. And I am not really confident with my English.

Comment: Do not forget Googling! A simple search could help you find similar sentences.

Comment: Such a tool is called a *diagnostic*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your sentence is perfectly grammatical, if a bit flowery. But "Does this correct?" is not grammatical. And I'm afraid **no** Stack Exchange site does proof-reading [although sometimes people get in under the wire.]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine "This is a diagnostic tool for unveiling an underlying disease". As such, it is correct. The "unveiling" is a rather poetic or imaginative metaphor but that seems to me a good thing, helping to create very good prose.